# Cipher text is not a multiple of block size

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++

I've written a simple AES encryption program for a piece of text and whenever I attempt to decrypt the text, I am thrown an error;

> StreamTransformationFilter: ciphertext length is not a multiple of block size

This is my method of encryption;

```
c_crypto::cryptkey aes_key;

c_crypto::make_keys(aes_key);

std::string testmessage = "test";

c_crypto::encrypt_buffer(testmessage, aes_key.enc_key, aes_key.enc_iv);
c_crypto::decrypt_buffer(testmessage, aes_key.enc_key, aes_key.enc_iv);

std::cout << testmessage << std::endl;
```

cryptkey struct;

```
struct cryptkey {
    unsigned char enc_key[AES_KEY_SIZE];
    unsigned char enc_iv[AES_KEY_SIZE];
};
```

`AES_KEY_SIZE` = 16

The `make_keys()` function simply calls;

```
void c_crypto::random_bytes(const int &amount, unsigned char *result) {
    CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool rng;
    rng.GenerateBlock(result, amount);
}
```

With the paramters of `AES_KEY_SIZE` of either `cryptkey.enc_iv` or `cryptkey.enc_key`

In the decrypt function;

```
void c_crypto::decrypt_buffer(std::string &input, unsigned char key[AES_KEY_SIZE], unsigned char iv[AES_KEY_SIZE]) {
    input = base64_decode(input);

    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, AES_KEY_SIZE);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(input));
    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(input.c_str()), input.size());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();
}
```

The error is thrown in stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

Here is the encrypt function if it is of any use;

```
void c_crypto::encrypt_buffer(std::string &input, unsigned char key[AES_KEY_SIZE], unsigned char iv[AES_KEY_SIZE]) {
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, AES_KEY_SIZE);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(input));
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(input.c_str()), input.length());
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    input = base64_encode(input);
}
```

EDIT:

Here's my decode and encode functions:

```
std::string c_crypto::base64_encode(std::string &input) {
    std::string result;
    CryptoPP::StringSource(input, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Encoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(result)));
    return result;
}

std::string c_crypto::base64_decode(std::string &input) {
    std::string result;
    CryptoPP::StringSource(input, true, new CryptoPP::Base64Decoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(result)));
    std::cout << (input.size() % 16 == 0) << std::endl;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: padd `testmessage` to a length of a multiple of the block size before feeding it to `encrypt_buffer()`?

Comment: @Swordfish check new edit

Comment: your `pad_to()` can be written much simpler using `std::string::append()`: `void pad_to(std::string &str, std::size_t num, char ch) { str.append(num - s.length(), ch); }

Comment: @jww Upon debugging, input.size in the decode function has a value of 37. I'll add the function right now.

Comment: @jww That was with the the padding function removed, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> void c_crypto::encrypt_buffer(std::string &input, unsigned char key[AES_KEY_SIZE], unsigned char iv[AES_KEY_SIZE]) {
>     CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, AES_KEY_SIZE);
>     CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);
>
>     CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(input));
>     stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(input.c_str()), input.length());
>     stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
>
>     input = base64_encode(input);
> }
> ```

Don't use the same string as a source and a sink like you are doing. Use a separate temporary instead.

Most (all?) block ciphers can take a 16-byte block and encrypt or decrypt in place. However, in the case of string, the as string changes the underlying allocation changes. When the allocation changes the underlying pointer changes.

Maybe use something like the following. The temporaries sidestep the problems of using a string as both a source and sink. It also provides better exception safety. If something goes sideways your `input` is left unchanged.

```
void c_crypto::encrypt_buffer(std::string &input, unsigned char key[AES_KEY_SIZE], unsigned char iv[AES_KEY_SIZE]) {
    AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, AES_KEY_SIZE);
    CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

    std::string encrypted; encrypted.reserve(input.size()+16);
    StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new StringSink(encrypted));
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(input.c_str()), input.length());
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

    std::string encoded = base64_encode(encrypted);
    std::swap(encoded, input);
}

void c_crypto::decrypt_buffer(std::string &input, unsigned char key[AES_KEY_SIZE], unsigned char iv[AES_KEY_SIZE]) {
    std::string decoded = base64_decode(input);
    std::string decrypted; decrypted.reserve(decoded.size());

    AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, AES_KEY_SIZE);
    CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

    StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new StringSink(decrypted));
    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(decoded.c_str()), decoded.size());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    std::swap(decrypted, input);
}
```

---

Using a buffer as an in/out parameter works fine. In this example the pointer will not change part way through the process:

```
byte buff[16] = {0};
CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc(key, 16, iv);
enc.ProcessBlock(buff);
```

However your use case is a little trickier because the cipher text is *appended* to the string `input` by way of `StringSink(input)`, which inevitably makes `input` grow and invalidates the iterators being used to feed the data into the encryptor via `StringSource(input, ...)`.

If interested, the `ProcessBlock` and `ProcessString` are the low-level member functions used to transform the data. Filters like `StreamTransformationFilter` simply calls it for you. There's no magic or mischief. It is just a high level way to process data. Also see [`BlockTransformation`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_block_transformation.html) in the doxygen manual.

---

Regarding padding, you used:

```
StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new StringSink(input));
```

Which is really this [`StreamTransformationFilter`](https://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_stream_transformation_filter.html) constructor:

```
StreamTransformationFilter (StreamTransformation &c, BufferedTransformation *attachment=NULL, BlockPaddingScheme padding=DEFAULT_PADDING)
```

`DEFAULT_PADDING` is one of two things. For modes that need padding, like ECB and CBC, it is PKCS #7 padding (`PKCS_PADDING`). For modes that *don't* need padding, like CTR, it is no padding (`NO_PADDING`).

You should usually take the default when it comes to padding schemes.